# MVC, change the style of action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action link like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(Name + " (" + Count+ ")", "ActonName", "Controller", new { ID= itemID}, null)%>
```

it shows

> football (5)

I want it displays like this:

> football **(5)**

I have try to change the actionlink like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink(Name + " <b>(" + Count+ ")</b>", "ActonName", "Controller", new { ID= itemID}, null)%>
```

it does not work. any idea to to this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActionLink` always encodes the text. You could use [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348.aspx):

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("ActonName", "Controller", new { ID = itemID }) %>">
    <b>(<%= Count %>)</b>
</a>
```

or write a custom HTML helper if you don't like the tag soup.